# Cropping whitespace from an Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, crop

Anyone know of a good method of cropping whitespace from an image? I have an external method which generates Image objects containing charts, but unfortunately they have lots of white space which I would like to remove.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution after googling for some different terms... Always happens...

For reference:

http://fitnessconnections.com/blog/remove-surrounding-white-space-from-an-image/

Comment: You'll want to mark this "Best Answer" or it'll continue to appear in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: the link goes to a link farm website